# Loading HDF5 with Matlab

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I need to open and visualize a binary file in HDF5 format with Matlab.

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/hdf5-files.html

Comment: Do I just type h5disp('example.h5','path/to/file') ?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has support for hdf5 files.
To get information about the data structure stored in a specific hdf5 file you can use [`hdf5info`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdf5info.html) function:

```
h5info = hdf5info('/path/to/file.hdf5');
```

Once you have the information, you can use it to read the data from the file unsing [`hdf5read`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdf5read.html):

```
data = hdf5read(h5info);
```

Comment: Thanks first of all! that created some files with info that I needed. My goal is to actually visualize my h5 files somehow. Do you know how to achieve this?